# How to make tag group with including predefined attributes, to wrap other things quickly?

Tags: css, xhtml, dreamweaver, code-snippets, code-templates

**for example.**

if i want to quickly wrap anything by this in once.

in dreamweaver or in any other free software where i can do this.

I want to select this

```
<p>anything can be here - content, other html tag etc.</p>
```

and in one shot want to wrap inside 2 `divs` with predefined classes

```
<div class="one">
      <div class="two">
<p>anything can be here - content, other html tag etc.</p>

      </div>
</div>
```

I have work with large amount of code and need to wrap random things in `Divs` with defined attributes.

Comment: Can you rewrite your question, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Are you asking how to automatically wrap some piece of HTML in some other (predefined) piece of HTML?

Comment: @Jan Hančič - Yes , in Dreamweaver...

Comment: but tag with predefined class

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer on my own after digging.

We can do this from Dreamweaver Snippet's "Insert before" and "Insert after" optiion

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/300767/11022382120-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/300767/11022382120-My-Desktop.png)